# Looking for recommendations for external RAID enclosures

Tags: drive-enclosure

I am looking for an external enclosure that meets the following specs:

1. 2.5" drive support is nominal, but 3.5" will work as adapters are readily available.
2. SATA III to USB 3.0.
3. 2 to 3 bay.
4. Price under $100 USD.
5. Has on-board RAID hardware with options for RAID0, JBOD, etc.
6. If possible, fans that can be replaced without requiring disassembly of the entire unit *if actively cooled*
7. Would prefer units with low failure rates.

RAID options are not my main focus at present but some options will help in the near future.

As I have been told, the places I have looked for reviews are opinion based, not objective.

Comment: To be fair, you won't find objective reviews on Amazon or Newegg, those are all subjective.

Comment: For all, this is the meta discussion: http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/579/57

Comment: I see your features list, but what criteria are you basing your notion of *objectivity* on?  Are you looking for certain additional qualities in an enclosure such as reliability, or are you simply having difficulty finding one that fits all of your bullets?