# Raid Enclosure Interface

Tags: raid, drive-enclosure

I'm looking for a drive enclosure that can do RAID 0 and maybe RAID 5.  All of the brand names run together on me, I have idea what brand to consider.  As I understand, the fastest interface is USB 3.1 and I have some of those in my computer, so it seems that's the best choice.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Do you have a budget? Also, how big of an array are you looking for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of a question [I asked back in October](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/6048/looking-for-recommendations-for-external-raid-enclosures)  Only difference being I stopped at USB 3.0 interface, and this is asking for 3.1 lol.

Comment: OP has over 4k rep on SO, so knowing how to be specific on questions should not be a problem.